# Is there a thing such as a Big-O-Notation of O(0)?

Tags: big-o, bubble-sort

I was wondering whether it is even possible as a concept to have a Big-O-Notation of O(0) (in a very specific scenario).

Imagine I have a list with values and I want to sort it with Bubblesort. Suppose, however, that the list is already sorted. If I'm not mistaken, this would have a Big-O-Notation of O(n), where n is the number of elements.

Now, I want to express the Big-O-Notation of the swaps I've had to make to get the list sorted. In this very specific scenario, no swaps were made. So, would I go about it by saying that the swaps' Big-O-Notation is O(0) or is the minimum I can have O(1), and why?

Comment: Big-O notation denotes how the complexity varies with the size of the input. The number of swaps on a sorted array (zero) is constant with respect to the length of the array, so it's `O(1)`.

Comment: Oh, thank you, that clears it up :D

Answer (score 0):

The simplest complexity is `O(1)`, constant time (or space, or whatever else you may be measuring, *including* number of swaps). That's constant, even if the value is zero.

In any case, sort functions are *not* O(1) because, at a minimum, you have to *check* it's sorted even if you don't make any swaps. Your particular measurement of swap count may give you O(1) but I'd be interested in the reasoning behind that being considered a useful metric :-)